# zypper exit code 106 - how to fix?

Tags: sles, zypper

On a SLES11.4 server wanted to install a package:

```
SLES11SERVER:~ # zypper in -f telnet
Retrieving repository 'foobar_common' metadata [\]
File 'repomd.xml' from repository 'foobar_common' is unsigned, continue? [yes/no] (no): yes
Retrieving repository 'foobar_common' metadata [error]
Repository 'foobar_common' is invalid.
[|] Valid metadata not found at specified URL(s)
Please check if the URIs defined for this repository are pointing to a valid repository.
Warning: Disabling repository 'foobar_common' because of the above error.
Some of the repositories have not been refreshed because of an error.
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Forcing installation of 'telnet-1.2-134.24.1.x86_64' from repository 'SLES11-SP4-Pool'.
Resolving package dependencies...

The following package is going to be reinstalled:
  telnet

1 package to reinstall.
Overall download size: 54.0 KiB. No additional space will be used or freed after the operation.
Continue? [y/n/? shows all options] (y): y
Retrieving package telnet-1.2-134.24.1.x86_64 (1/1), 54.0 KiB (118.0 KiB unpacked)
Retrieving: telnet-1.2-134.24.1.x86_64.rpm [done]
Installing: telnet-1.2-134.24.1 [done]
SLES11SERVER:~ # echo $?
106
SLES11SERVER:~ #
```

According to the man page:

```
106 - ZYPPER_EXIT_INF_REPOS_SKIPPED
           Some repository had to be disabled temporarily because it failed to refresh. You should check your
           repository configuration (e.g.  zypper ref -f).
```

So I did a "zypper ref -f":

```
SLES11SERVER:~ # zypper ref -f
...
Retrieving repository 'foobar_common' metadata [/]
File 'repomd.xml' from repository 'foobar_common' is unsigned, continue? [yes/no] (no): yes
Retrieving repository 'foobar_common' metadata [error]
Repository 'foobar_common' is invalid.
[|] Valid metadata not found at specified URL(s)
Please check if the URIs defined for this repository are pointing to a valid repository.
Skipping repository 'foobar_common' because of the above error.
Forcing raw metadata refresh
...
Some of the repositories have not been refreshed because of an error.
SLES11SERVER:~ #
```

The package got installed (from another repo, this foobar_common doesn't provides it), but I must have exit code 0 for zypper after a package install.

**Q:** How can I fix that the zypper will not give exit code 106?

I tried to:

- delete/add the foobar_common repo, same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the repository side (PEBKAC for the operating team for the repo :) )

Also, `zypper clean --all` helps.